"Next.js Production Build Error: '.next' Directory Not Found"
Error: Could not find a production build in the '.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id     at setupFsCheck (E:\crs admin and client\skillonorofffrontend\node_modules\next\dist\ser
i did run npm run build
but the problem repeating itself but not solving
solution for the problem

You have to verify if the .next folder is created after next build command and please tell about the server you use to make application live

.next folder is created
i am trying in my personal before putting in production

Ok i get it but you are trying it in your computer but i just want to ask about the as it not working with npm start after build or your are using any other server to host the app...?


Sometimes, clearing the Next.js build cache can resolve this issue.
Delete the .next folder manually, and then run npm run build again.
package.json has the correct script to start the production server.
It should be something like this:



"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "husky"
  },




i did them but still same error i am getting
Error: Could not find a production build in the '.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
at setupFsCheck (E:\crs admin and client\skillonorofffrontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\filesystem.js:148:19)
at async initialize (E:\crs admin and client\skillonorofffrontend\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:65:23)
at async Server.

Hello did you check the package.json
